# How to merge two topics in kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have  two topics in the broker. Without consuming from one topic, I want to merge both topics, and will consume messages from the second topic.

It is because, I have two processes, one process, pushes messages to topic A. And the second process once finished processing, it wants to merge both topicA and TopicB.
Then another process will consume messages from the merged topic.

How can I merge both topics in high level kafka APIs. I use Kafka 0.10.0.1

Comment: were you able to solve this problem, I have a very similar use case.